# AngularJS ng-form alternatives in IE8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-ng-form

I am developing a SPA with AngularJS which needs to support IE 8.

In one of the page I am having nested forms using `<form>` and `<ng-form>` for form validation:

```
<form>
    <!-- Some input and checkbox elements -->
    <div class="well" ng-repeat="member in data.teammembers">
        <ng-form name="innerForm">
            <!-- Other repeating form elements -->
        </ng-form>
    </div>
</form>
```

However, as you may already know by now, that custom elements are not being treated properly in IE 8. All I get is a blank page now. If I remove `<ng-form></ng-form>`, everything is back to normal.

I have already setup `<html>` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="myApp" id="ng-app" ng-cloak>
```

And I have also included [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim)

So my question is:

Are there any `<ng-form>` alternatives so that I can use form validation in nested forms which can render in IE 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngForm` directive has `EAC` restriction for generic html tags (not the `form` tag) [ngForm API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)
So, you can change your HTML as this:

```
<form>
    <!-- Some input and checkbox elements -->
    <div class="well" ng-repeat="member in data.teammembers">
        <div ng-form="innerForm">
            <!-- Other repeating form elements -->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And better to give `name` attribute to outer form. This way can access outer form's controller properties and methods.

Comment: Just a note that if you really want to use it as an element you can make IE happy with `document.createElement('ng-form');` via https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie